# Can't create an array in a C++ header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl

I'm developing a game in SDL and in the file InputPC.h I'm trying to create an bool[] myarray to register the state of the keys, due the abstraction and multi-platform I have to use this way of "asking" for the keys.

```
Class InputPC { 
public: 
InputPC(); 
~InputPC(); 
static void Tick();

static bool a;
static bool w;
static bool s;
static bool d;
static bool[] myarray;
static bool getA();
static bool getW();
static bool getS();
static bool getD();
};
```

The line myarray is always red, (I have tried not to use static)

Comment: This `static bool[] myarray;` is not legal `C++` syntax. It looks a bit like `Java`.

Comment: @Galik What I should do instead?

Comment: `static bool myarray[myarraysize];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just I declare my array like that
    bool inputs[10];